# Should we add the History of Genealogy to our 'on-topic' subjects?

Tags: discussion, scope

We've recently had a question about the History of Genealogy: [Who is (was) Gertrude Aubrey Barber, compiler of thousands of Grave inscriptions?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/18367/6485).

Strictly speaking it's off-topic, as our scope is currently defined. Although it could have been moulded into a question about assessing the quality of the source transcriptions concerned, that wasn't why it was asked, and it seems to me (at least) a little perverse to do so.

Is the History of Genealogy something we want to include in our scope?

Note: I do NOT want to discuss the merits of that particular question, but only a possible extension of our scope.

Comment: I honestly don't know if I should comment on this question, but personally take exception to being categorized as inept (Q " could have been moulded" ) and further the assignment of a motive that was "perverse". As a novice I thought it better to be brief rather than verbose in asking the original question, as it was I assumed that helpful people would guide to to finding out about Barber's work. I did not anticipate that I should have to discuss what I found to be lacking in her work (my **subjective**  evaluation) whist asking the question.... then again I'm practically a newbie.

Comment: On politics SE not nearly the degree of nit-picking linguistic purity demanded. Genealogy and family history is not the friendly site. BTW, Barbar complied a great many works that did not pertain to NY, so I fail to understand your edit of tags.  —- but that is just being “picky”.

Comment: @BobE I would be happy to discuss your question in chat, as one user to another, not with my mod hat on.  I apologize for making you feel unwelcome on the site.  I think we have been talking past each other and would welcome a chance to explain, but doing it in comments isn't the best place.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in two minds about altering our scope to include questions about the History of Genealogy/Family History.

As Adrian said at https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3518/6485, I'm not sure we (as a community) could do justice to those questions -- doing a quick google to point to published resources isn't bringing any expertise to bear.

Asking questions about how and by whom a resource was produced in the past because it might affect how you assess the quality of that resource... that could be seen as part of "Finding a source or understanding how to use it", and thus in scope.

However, other questions about the history of our subject should IMO be on-topic as well, whether we can handle them well or not.

Answer (score 3):

If we include the history of Family History and Genealogy to our on-topic questions, I would like to see them held to the same standards as any other question on the site.

**Can we avoid these pitfalls when asking and answering the questions?**

- [How to Ask Questions in Private Beta](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask-beta) advises us to **Avoid Easy Questions** such as "what are some good books on this topic" or "what are the best blogs on this topic".  See the blog post [Are Some Questions Too Simple?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/22/are-some-questions-too-simple/)  This is similar to the advice to [avoid asking](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) subjective questions where every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) discusses the problem of **Scope:** "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."  (If books, monographs or multi-part series of articles in genealogical journals already exist on the life or work of a specific genealogist, these "it could be a book" questions are likely to generate link-only answers, as users point to the book, monograph, or journal. For example, when I answered this question from History SE, [What were the reasons for the Federal Art Project?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/11315/3467), I tried to avoid posting a single link-only answer by adding a pointer to the relevant record group at the US National Archives.)
- We're advised to [avoid asking](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) questions where there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.” (We've already seen several questions about the history of particular surnames that fall into this category, where the asker is curious to know the history of a particular surname, doesn't show any research effort, nor cites any specific information they could use to solve a specific research question. It's not wrong to be curious about things, but if we have no actual problem to be solved, it's more tempting to be vague and too broad.)

**What makes for a good question about the History of Genealogy and Family History?**

I personally prefer questions where users are asking about a problem that they are currently working on in genealogy and family history,because I think it's easier to focus on specific research questions when we have a problem we're thinking about. But whether we have a specific research question or we're writing up our own research in a self-answered question, most of all I would like to see users follow the guidelines from [How do I ask a good question?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), including:

- **Be Specific:** "If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer."
- **Search and Research**: "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant
  answer!"
- **Make it relevant to others**: "We like to help as many people at a time as we can. Make it clear how your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us will be interested in your question and willing to look into it."

I would certainly welcome *self-answered* questions on the history of family history and genealogy. If someone in the community has investigated the work of particular genealogists, and wants to share their findings with the community in a self-answered question for the benefit of the community, that's very different than a user simply expressing idle curiosity about a broad topic in the history of genealogy itself and expecting others to write up answers or do the research for them.

**"But I can't find anything!" or the Negative Finding Blues**

We've all had cases where we have wanted to learn more about a particular topic, have done some searches, and haven't been able to find anything useful. In cases like that, I think it's better to put a brief statement to that effect in the question, and perhaps to ask what keywords might yield more productive searches.  A statement of negative findings shows that the user has made some effort. If the user says nothing, we can't tell what searches they've made or if they've made any searches at all.

Answer (score 1):

How many of us can seriously contribute to such questions, I wonder? Very few I guess (emphasis on guess). I really only have a vague idea, and even there I feel that what I call Genealogy and what I call Family History, is pretty much opposite to what Americans seem to use those terms for. It could be that I'm just ignorant, of course, but my gut feeling is that doing the topic justice is not possible for us. Maybe that in itself needs to be recorded somewhere as a justification if we carry on excluding the topic.